# Set a maximum number of signups

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a form where people can choose a team.

Is there a way to create a maximum of registered people per team?

For instance, 40 people can register for team A and another 40 can register for Team B.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support this feature, but it is on our Next Up list on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/wCL0grb2).  The key here is providing a easy way to create forms that include one or more quantity-limited items, and then make it easy to review and update quantities as new entries are submitted and as external factors affect available inventory.